# Android ArrayList: Store Multiple Values Into A Profile

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist

I have multiple variables, we'll call them `varA`, `varB`, `varC`, and `varD`. When a button is pressed these `4 variables` are to be stored in an ArrayList, together. This creates a single entry which can be viewed by variable varA. All the entries can be viewed in a `ListView` which is done through an `ArrayAdapter`.

**onCreate**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> profileAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    profileList.setAdapter(profileAdapter);
```

**When a button is pressed**

```
// Add data to a new profile in @+id/profileList ListView
ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(varA);
System.out.println("varA's");
System.out.println(arrayList);
((ArrayAdapter)profileList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Layout**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/overviewLayout">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/profileList"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am having issues with the ListView showing the items that were added. Also, I was trying to use `TinyDB` to store these items so they can be referenced later since that ArrayList used on button press is just temporary. I also I'm having trouble figuring out how to set this up so that each time the button is pressed those 4 vars will stay together in a "profile" so they don't get mixed up with some other data that might be added later.

Comment: Describe more in detail, what kind of issues do you have?

Comment: Well first off I'm trying to use ((ArrayAdapter)profileList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); to update the listview but the listview is only updating after I re-build the application. How can I refresh my list view?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeated values from getting stored  check if it already exists :

```
    if(!arrayList.contains(varA)){
      arrayList.add(varA); 
    }
```

For listview updation problem ,use notifyItemInserted(position) instead of notifyDataSetChanged()

```
     yourAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to display a list which contains 4 datas in one entry and showing just the first of them.

If it is, you could create a custom `Model`, it will be easier. This will store your datas in one object:

```
ProfileModel
    |
    |-- varA
    |-- varB
    |-- varC
    '-- varD
```

Your custom model could look like something like this:

```
public class ProfileModel {

    private String varA;
    private float varB;
    private int varC;
    private String varD;

    // getters
    ...
    // setters
    ...

    public ProfileModel() { } 
}
```

Initialize the list of profiles at start:

```
ArrayList<ProfileModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

To populate the main list do as follows:

```
// create a list of object to the datas
ProfileModel profile = new ProfileModel();
profile.setVarA(varA);
profile.setVarB(varB);
profile.setVarC(varC);
profile.setVarD(varD);
// then fill the first list
list.add(profile);
```

Since you want to fill the adapter with other datas than a simple `String` but a custom model, I'd prefer to use a custom adapter. It's not that hard to create one, and because sometimes, you maybe want a different behavior on an update, I'd also prefer to use a custom `notifyDataSetChanged` method.
So, here's a simple adapter with the same layout as the one you used:

```
public class ProfileAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ProfileModel> listProfiles;

    public ProfileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProfileModel> listProfiles) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.listProfiles = listProfiles;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView textVarA;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listProfiles != null ? listProfiles.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return listProfiles.get(i); // will return the profile model from position
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
            holder.textVarA = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        ProfileModel profile = listProfiles.get(i);
        holder.textVarA.setText(profile.getVarA()); // get varA value

        return view;
    }

    public void addEntry(ProfileModel newEntry) {
        listProfiles.add(newEntry);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Then, you can set the adapter as follows:

```
ProfileAdapter profileAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(this, list);
profileList.setAdapter(profileAdapter);
```

To update this adapter:

```
// create a list of object to the datas
ProfileModel profile = new ProfileModel();
profile.setVarA(varA);
profile.setVarB(varB);
profile.setVarC(varC);
profile.setVarD(varD);
profileAdapter.addEntry(profile); // this will call notifyDataSetChanged
```

Finally, I'm not very aware about `TinyDB`, but I saw it's using some JSON file to store data. So you could create a method to convert your datas to JSONArray which its name is `varA` and has values `varB, varC, varD`. There is many examples how to convert datas to JSON (as using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert your model to a JSON format).

Hope this will be useful.